# Ionic 2 & Angularfire2 + Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ionic2, angularfire2

I'm using AngularFire2 as a provider in Ionic 2. I'm making a basic list app. Below is my data that is in Firebase.

```
{
  "Checklists" : {
    "0" : {
      "title" : "new List"
    },
    "-KYHODAYcQ4OKMAzcXSG" : {
      "items" : [ {
        "checked" : "false",
        "title" : "Milk"
      } ],
      "title" : "Newest List"
    },
    "-KYHS654NUHiwkexMwhL" : {
      "items" : [ {
        "checked" : "false",
        "title" : "asdfadf"
      } ],
      "title" : "ddddd"
    }
  }
}
```

I have this all pulling in just fine in my home view and updating the title for each checklist with no problem. I'm retrieving the data by using this code in my data provider class and then calling it in my `home.ts`. This works fine by the way.

```
this.checklists = angFire.database.list('/Checklists');
```

The problem comes when I navigate to a new view in my app. So I use this code to move to the checklist-items view and pass the current checklist.

```
this.checklist = this.navParams.get('checklist');
```

So now, in the checklist-items view, I have a reference to the current checklist along with title and items if the checklist has them. If I have them already in Firebase, this works fine.

The problem is how to add an item or the items array to one of the checklist if it doesn't exist in Firebase. I can do that in the view now with no problem by doing this,

```
if(this.checklist.items && this.checklist.items.length > 0){
    this.checklist.items.push({title: data.name, checked:"false"});
}else{
    this.checklist.items = [{title: data.name, checked:"false"}];
    console.log(this.checklist);
}
```

It is when I want to update it to Firebase that I run into a problem. I can get it to update one checklist with an initial array of items by doing this in my data provider.

```
this.checklists.update(id, {items: [
        {
            title: itemTitle,
            checked: "false"
        }
    ]});
```

but this will overwrite anything that is already there.

I need to get a reference to the current checklist and see if there is a items array but I can not find any documentation on this. I have tried ref, but that will not work. Any help would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up getting it to work, but not sure if it is the right way to do this. In the checklist-items view I add the items to the current checklist.items array by doing this

```
**this is the checklist-items view**
if(this.checklist.items && this.checklist.items.length > 0){
    this.checklist.items.push({title: data.name, checked:"false"});
}else{
    this.checklist.items = [{title: data.name, checked:"false"}];
    console.log(this.checklist);
}
```

Then I call the function to add and item in my data provider class and send it the entire checklist that has the entire items array.

```
this.data.addItem(this.checklist);
```

Then in my data provider, I simply overwrite the entire items array in the current checklist by doing this in my data provider class.

```
**this is the data-provider view**
addItem(checklist):void {
    let checklistId = checklist.$key;

    this.checklists.update(checklistId, {items: checklist.items});
}
```

This works but like I said don't know if it is the proper way.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest not to use array in storing data. Array is stored as an object with integers as the key names. These integers are not reliable because they are not a permanent key. If an item in the array gets deleted, you submit the whole array and the items will have a new integer key.

suggested data structure:

```
 checklist
    -key
        items
            -itemKey
                name: "milk"
                checked: true
            -itemKey
                name: "bread"
                checked: false      
            -itemKey
                name: "sugar"
                checked: true           
        title: "newest list"
```